# how to grab an id in a table in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

trying to grab the id in mysql from my table if u click manage I want it to grab the id of that specific data  [image]

not sure on how I go about this have tried a couple ways and there not working I'm trying to make a ticket system with out using someone else's source code just looking for someones assistance

```
<div class="dt-card__body">

<div class="card-body mb-1 pt-0">
    <div class="table-responsive mb-0 pt-0">
    <table class="table datatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">ID</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">Unique id</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">Title</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">Message</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">Department</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">resolved?</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">manage</th>
                <th class="text-uppercase" scope="col">close</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $all_t_values = $c_con->query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE username='$username'");
            foreach($all_t_values as $t_value){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['uniqid']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['title']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['init_msg']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['department']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $t_value['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php
                if($t_value['resolved'] == 1){
                    echo "open";
                }

               // echo $t_value['resolved']; 
               ?></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="delete_token" value=""> manage</button></td>

                <td><button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="delete_token" value=""> close</button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

I wanna grab the id from a row where the data shows, as I'm trying to make a function that will edit the data on that row but I wanna know how to grab the id on that row

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: sorry ive fixed it

Comment: `"... I'm trying to make a function that will edit the data on that row..."` - a Javascript function to edit content or a PHP function to modify and save content? As you have not shown a `form` element in the above the `button` will simply act as a button so I assume Javascript/Ajax is the intended method? You could use PHP to write the `$t_value['id']` value as a dataset attribute on the parent table row and easily find that using javascript and the click `event`

Answer (score 0):

Next time please do not post code as an image

Assuming that you mean you want the get the value of id and use it in a button, then you should use something like:

```
<?php echo $t_value['id']; ?>
```

So if you have a proper form element to submit to the server, then change:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="delete_token" value=""> manage</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="delete_token" value="<?php echo $t_value['id']; ?>"> manage</button>
```

However, if you actually do not have a form element to submit the data, then you may use the GET method to do the job (such as calling a delete.php):

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $t_value['id']; ?>">
<button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" name="delete_token" manage</button></a>
```